# Solution for jumping Safari table caption?

Tags: css, animation, safari

anyone has a solution for what appears to be a Safari bug? When a transform CSS is applied to a table content, the caption jumps to the end of table.

There was a hint using "will-change: transform" for the caption with [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44009186/safari-bug-translating-table-row-group-using-gsap-make-caption-jump-to-bottom?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but unfortunately it does not work here.

See codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GxVWzV

HTML:

```
<table>
<caption>
  Caption
</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr onclick="collapse(this)">
      <td></td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
tbody tr > td:first-child:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 6px solid black;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: .7rem;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
  transition: transform .2s ease-out;
  pointer-events:auto;
}
tbody tr.collapsed > td:first-child:before {
  content: ' ';
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(-3px);
}
```

JS:

```
function collapse(e) {
  e.classList.toggle("collapsed");
}
```

NOTE: Fixed in Safari 15.1

Comment: Hi any updates on the issue? The only fix I have encountered till now is to set position absolute inside caption as suggested in link

Comment: @HargunSingh No, it's still jumping in Safari. Other browsers work ok, this one is Safari's bug and still listed as an open bug in Apple bug system. absolute positioning of the caption is not an option as it messes up the layout.

Comment: can you please share a link of where the bug is posted for reference

Comment: don't position caption absolutely try this <caption><span style="position:absolute"> Your Content</span></caption>

Comment: @HargunSingh The Apple bugtracking (feedbackassistant nowadays) is not open to public. You can only see your own submits. The absolute positioning of the span works when you use JS to set the caption height to be the same as the span height (otherwise the caption height is 0). That is doable. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. If the above solution works for you can I post it as an answer for your question?

Comment: If the content of the caption is static,  this will work with the JS. The problem is that if the content height for the caption changes dynamically (as in my case), it becames a hassle to track the height of the caption. The bug has been open in Apple for couple of years already, so probably not in top of the priority list.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in Safari 15.1.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue with `caption-side: top;` in iOS Safari.

Try add the following CSS:

```
caption {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that changes the rendering and puts the caption under the header. You can see the effect in CodePen.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe this isn't fixed by now.

What I did, in jQuery, is detach the caption and then reattach:

```
$('table').prepend($('caption').detach());
```

Comment: Yes, that puts the caption in it's place, but it still jumps first into wrong place when the transition starts. Still waiting for Apple to fix this. It's only been couple of years since the bug report.